# How to sort Gridview items

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sorting, gridview

I have a dynamically created `gridview` in c# asp.net that I need sorted when you load the page. How can this be done? I am using `gridview1.DataBind()` to bind.

Comment: please ne more elaborate if you need real help.

Comment: Use a `DataView` -> sort it and then bind that dataview to your grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
DataTable table = GetTable();
table.DefaultView.Sort = "SortCondition";

//
// Display all records in the view.
//
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
```

Now Bind the grid

```
 GridView1.DataSource=view;
 GirdView1.DataBind();
```